How to find Monthly Active Users (MAU)?
Dataset Overview:
Table Name: data
Fields:
event_date (DATE)
user_id (STRING)
user_first_touch_timestamp (INTEGER)

Objective: Finding Monthly Active Users (MAU) using SQL
This is my attempted code:
SELECT 
    user_id,
    DATE_FORMAT(event_date, '%Y-%m') AS month,
    COUNT(DISTINCT event_date) AS MAU
FROM 
    your_table_name
GROUP BY 
    user_id, DATE_FORMAT(event_date, '%Y-%m');

Could you help me double check my code? and, for some reasons, the question doesn't attach any real data set for me to test so how can I create a hypothesis dataset?

That doesn't seem right. At a glance, it finds number of events in a given month, per user. MAU is something else. Definitions vary from company to company, I imagine, but you could define it "user who had at least one event in a given month" as a starting point.

Which dbms are you using? (The above query is product specific.)

Note that tables have columns, not fields.

https://dbfiddle.uk/ can be used for testing purposes.

The starting point would be to provide a definition for MAU
